# Ajax call issue

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, reactjs, react-redux

I'm sending an image attribute file by ajax call. But the post api might be constantly breaking for this. I want to push the file in the image attribute array in the formData & have the successful api call.

My Api form data configuration is as shown in the following image:
[image]

When I'm checking the formData image attribute array on Console I'm getting the thing **image attributes[]: [object file]** as shown in the following image: 
[image]
& my api is constantly failing and showing the following error: 
[image]
Following is the code I'm currently stuck on:

/*NewPost.jsx */

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("Submitting")
        let error = this.areThereAnyErrors();
        if(!error){
          let data = {};
          data.description = this.state.description.value || "";
          // console.log(this.state.images_attributes);
          data.images_attributes = this.state.images_attributes[0] || null;
          let brand_string = this.state.brand_ids[0].value;
          let brands_list = this.props.auto_complete_details.brand_json;
          let selected_brand = brands_list.find(function (brand) {
            return brand.brand_name.toLowerCase() == brand_string.toLowerCase();
          });
          if(selected_brand){
            this.state.brand_selected.value = selected_brand.brand_id;
          }

          if(this.state.brand_selected.value){
            data.Brand = this.state.brand_selected.value;
          } else {
            // console.log(this.state.brand_ids);
            data.custom_brand = this.state.brand_ids[0].value;
          }


          let product_string = this.state.product_ids[0].value;
          let product_list = this.props.auto_complete_details.product_json;
          let selected_product = product_list.find(function (product) {
            return product.product_name.toLowerCase() == product_string.toLowerCase();
          });
          if(selected_product){
            this.state.product_selected.value = selected_product.product_id;
          }


          if(this.state.product_selected.value){
            data.Product = this.state.product_selected.value;
          } else {
            data.custom_product = this.state.product_ids[0].value;
          }

          data.Price = this.state.price.value;
          this.props.onFormSubmit(data);
   }
 }

render() {
    return(
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <div className={"row description new_post_desc "+error_class}>
          <div className="col-md-12 col-xs-12" style={{"paddingRight":"0px"}}>
              <textarea id="new_post_desc" name="description" className='new-post-description'   placeholder="Share your brand story..."  ref={(input) => {this.state.description = input}}/>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="description">
            <div className="row">
              <input id="new_post_image" className={this.state.errors.images_attributes ? "error-input disp_inline": "disp_inline"} type="file" name="image" accept="image/*" ref={(input) => {this.state.images_attributes[0] = input}} />
            </div>
            <div className="row margin-top-10">
              <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 new_post_spacing">
                <input id='autocomplete_brand' className={this.state.errors.brand_ids ? 'typeahead error-input new_post_capsules tt-hint hint_user_info' : 'typeahead new_post_capsules hint_user_info'} type="text" name="brand" placeholder="Brand" ref={(input) => {this.state.brand_ids[0] = input}}/>
                <input id="brand_value_selected" style={{display: "none"}} value="" ref={(input) => {this.state.brand_selected = input}}/>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 new_post_spacing">
                <input id='autocomplete_product' className={this.state.errors.product_ids ? 'typeahead error-input new_post_capsules tt-hint hint_user_info' : 'typeahead new_post_capsules hint_user_info'} type="text" name="product" placeholder="Product" ref={(input) => {this.state.product_ids[0] = input}}/>
                <input id="product_value_selected" style={{display: "none"}} value="" ref={(input) => {this.state.product_selected = input}} />
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 new_post_spacing">
                <input id='autocomplete_price' className={this.state.errors.price ? 'typeahead new_post_capsules tt-hint hint_user_info error-input' : 'typeahead new_post_capsules tt-hint hint_user_info'} type="number" name="price" placeholder="Price" ref={(input) => {this.state.price = input}}/>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-3 new_post_spacing">
                <button type="submit" className="btn button-styling" style={{"outline":"none"}} disabled={this.props.new_post_creation_in_progress}>Share { loading_icon }</button>  
              </div>
            </div>     
        </div>
        <div className="row">
            { this.state.has_errors ? <div className="error_mesg">* Please provide required information</div> : '' }
        </div>
    </form>
  );
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch, ownProps) => {
  var that = this;
  return {
    dispatch,
    onFormSubmit: (data) => {
        dispatch(getNewPostDetails(data));
    }
  };
}
```

/* Actions/index.js */

```
export const getNewPostDetails = (data) => {


console.log(data);
  var data_value = data;
  return function(dispatch) {
    var formData = new FormData();

    // add assoc key values, this will be posts values
    // setting form data

    console.log(data_value);

    //for image files
    if(data_value.images_attributes) {
      formData.append('images_attributes[]', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
    }


    //for video files
    formData.append('video_attributes[]', null);

    //for custom brands
    if(data_value.custom_brand) {
      formData.append('brand_ids[]', data_value.custom_brand);
    }

    //for products
    if(data_value.custom_product) {
      formData.append('product_ids[]', data_value.custom_product);
    }

    //For Price & Description
    formData.append('price', data_value.Price);
    formData.append('description', data_value.description);

    for (let pair of formData.entries()) {
      console.log(pair[0] + ': ' + pair[1]); 
    }

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: `${mainurl}/api/v1/posts`,
      // headers: checkAuthHeaders(), // the main solution
      formData: formData,
      beforeSend: function(){
        $("#new_post_desc").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#autocomplete_brand").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#autocomplete_product").prop('disabled', true);
        $("#autocomplete_price").prop('disabled', true);
        dispatch(createPostProgress(true));
       },
      success: function(resp) {
        $('#new_post_desc').val("");
        $('#new_post_image').val("");
        $('#autocomplete_brand').val("");
        $('#autocomplete_product').val("");
        $('#autocomplete_price').val("");
        $("#brand_value_selected").val("");
        $("#product_value_selected").val("");
        $("#new_post_desc").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#autocomplete_brand").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#autocomplete_product").prop('disabled', false);
        $("#autocomplete_price").prop('disabled', false);

        dispatch(receiveNewPostDetails(resp));
        dispatch(resetNewPostFlag());
        dispatch(createPostProgress(false));
      },
      error: function(error) {
        dispatch(createPostProgress(false));
      },
      async: true,
      cache: false,
      contentType: false,
      processData: false,
      timeout: 60000
    });
  };
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` At the end of the name of the attribute, it usually already means that this field is an array, and the value of this field should not be an array. So try to use:

```
formData.append('images_attributes[]', files[0]);
formData.append('images_attributes[]', files[1]);
formData.append('images_attributes[]', files[2]);
// etc..
```

Instead of

```
formData.append('images_attributes[]', files);
```

The same rule applies to other fields.

Comment: Your answer was right. But the error I was getting was for another issue. I am updating my code as the issue got resolved. The issue was about sending **headers** in the ajax post request. I was getting the error because of sending **headers** with sending **formData**. So I just commented out the **headers portion** in the Ajax call and the issue got resolved and your solution also helped me which I was actually doing wrong by sending the value of the fields as array. Thanks a lot for that :)